WPML Causing Redirection Issues on Home Page with WordPress Multisite and Custom Domain
I'm facing an issue with my WordPress Multisite setup and the WPML translation plugin. Here are the details:
Setup:
Main site URL: example.com
Subdirectory site URLs: example.com/site1, example.com/site2, etc.
Custom domain for subdirectory site: customdomain.com (redirected from example.com/site1)
Problem:
I'm using the WPML translation plugin for multilingual support across my multisite network. However, I'm encountering a redirection issue specifically on the home page of a subdirectory site that has been redirected to a custom domain.
When I switch the language using the WPML language switcher on the home page of the custom domain (customdomain.com), it redirects me to example.com/site1/?lang=en instead of staying within the custom domain (customdomain.com/?lang=en).
Interestingly, this problem only occurs on the home page. If I navigate to another page, such as customdomain.com/another-page, everything works perfectly with the language switcher. Additionally, if I set another page as the home page, the issue persists, indicating that the problem is isolated to the home page.
Example:
Network subdirectory site URL: example.com/site1
Custom domain URL: customdomain.com
Using the language switcher on customdomain.com redirects to example.com/site1/?lang=en instead of customdomain.com/?lang=en.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to fix this redirection problem?
